# Bayesian structure learning: how to identify z as a collider in x-z-y structure?

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network, conditional-independence

In BNSL(Bayesian Network Structure Learning) problem, we are asked to learn a DAG(Directed Acyclic Graph) over a randon variable set $U$, given samples of the underlying distribution of $U$. The traditional constraint-based method, such as SGS algorithms[1] and PC algorithms[2], first find a skeleton(an undirected graph $G$) for all variables by IT(independence test). Then for any induced subgraph like $x-z-y$($x$ and $y$ are not adjacent in $G$), they again use IT to decide whether the middle node $z$ is a collider or not. Specifically, $z$ is decided as a collider if $x$ and $y$ are dependent given every subset of $U-\{x,y\}$ containing $z$.

This is obviously true if $z$ is a collider in the underlying DAG. But do we have to test the independence of $x$ and $y$ for *all* subsets of $U-\{x,y\}$ containing $z$? Why can't we just test the independent given $z$? Since the other three structures(two chains and one fork) would suggest independence between $x$ and $y$ given $z$ and the collider structure is the only possible structure that would lead to a dependence result. Can anyone explain the necessity of checking the independence of $x$ and $y$ conditioning on every subset of $U-\{x,y\}$ containing $z$? Thanks in advance!

**update(1)**: "the other three structures" refers to $x\rightarrow z\rightarrow y$, $x\leftarrow z\leftarrow y$ and $x\leftarrow z\rightarrow y$. My reasoning is as follows: If the underlying structure for $x-z-y$ is any of these three, then $x\perp\!\!\!\perp y\:|\:z$. Otherwise, the underlying structure for $x-z-y$ must be $x\rightarrow y\leftarrow z$, which implies $x\perp\!\!\!\perp\!\!\!\!\!\!/ \:\:\:y\:|\:z$. So if IT tells us that $x\perp\!\!\!\perp\!\!\!\!\!\!/ \:\:\:y\:|\:z$, the other three structure can be ruled out and thus we immediately conclude that $x\rightarrow y\leftarrow z$ without testing the independence of $x$ and $y$ conditioning on other sets in $U\setminus \{x,y\}\cup\{z\}$.

[1] Spirtes, Peter, Clark N Glymour, and Richard Scheines. "Causality from Probability." Vol. 112. Carnegie-Mellon University, Laboratory for Computational Linguistics, 1989.

[2] Spirtes, Peter, and Clark Glymour. “An Algorithm for Fast Recovery of Sparse Causal Graphs.” Social Science Computer Review 9, no. 1 (April 1, 1991): 62–72. https://doi.org/10.1177/089443939100900106.

Comment: "This is obviously true if  is a collider" - why is it true that z is a collider if y is a collider? not obvious to me

Comment: @ihadanny sorry it's a typo, $y$ should be $z$

Comment: "The other three structures" - unless the Z is the *only* node in the remaining set, then surely there's many more possibilities - Z may be a sink or a source for a number of indirect interactions, doesn't it?

Comment: @jkm Thanks for your comment, jkm! My reply is too long to be in a comment. Please check out my update on the question.

Comment: @jkm What do you mean by "sink or a source for a number of indirect interactions"? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: If the cardinality of $U$ > 3, there's a set $H = U-{x,y,z}$ of additional variables in the skeleton. This creates additional possibilities, say, X->Z->H->Y, or X->H->Y->Z->H, or Z<-X->H->Z->Y and so on. The only way to be *sure* is to prove Z is a collider between X&Y *specifically* is to rule all of those out.

Comment: @jkm The first step of SGS and PC algorithms is to construct an undirected graph according whether or not two variables are directly dependent. That is, only when x and y are dependent given any subset of U-{x,y}, there will be an edge between x and y.  We call this undirected graph skeleton. If x-z-y is an induced subgraph in skeleton, none of your listed graphs is possible. Since there must be an directed between x and z, so be y and z. Also note that not all your listed graphs are DAGs.

Comment: @jkm Do you mean the variable H is a hidden variable which is unobservable?

Comment: @John not *necessarily* unobservable, just a variable without a known set of dependencies. Hidden variables satisfy that simply because, well, you cannot check what you cannot see. That said, I clearly need to read up on these algorithms before I dig myself any deeper here.